# Why doesnt my js calculator combiend with the html work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a mark calculator with javascript and css. the css isn`t working and I don't know how to solve it.

I have tried simple things on changing the js. The html form should be fine.

```js
   document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("input", rechne);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  function rechne () {
    var mathe = document.getElementById('mathe'),
        deutsch = document.getElementById('deutsch'),
        englisch = document.getElementById('englisch'),
        franzoesisch = document.getElementById('franzoesisch'),

    var schnitt  = mathe.valueAsNumber + deutsch.valueAsNumber + englisch.valueAsNumber + franzoesisch.valueAsNumber;

    schnitt = schnitt.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('notenschnitt')
    .value = schnitt;

    document.getElementById("notenschnitt")
      .addEventListener("input", rechne);
    }
  );
}
```

```html
    <form id="myForm">
        <legend>Notenrechner</legend>

         <label for="mathe">Mathe</label>
         <input type="number" min="1" max="6" id="mathe" value="0" step="0.5">

         <label for="deutsch">Deutsch</label>
         <input type="number" min="1" max="6" id="deutsch" value="0" step="0.5">

         <label for="englisch">Englisch</label>
         <input type="number" min="1" max="6" id="englisch" value="0" step="0.5">

         <label for="franzoesisch">Franz&ouml;sisisch</label>
         <input type="number" min="1" max="6" id="franzoesisch" value="0" step="0.5">

         <span>Notenschnitt</span>
         <output id="notenschnitt" for="ergebnis">0</output>

   </form>
```

Comment: What isn't working, specifically? What does it currently do that you do not want it to? How should it work?

Comment: I do not see any css code.

Comment: Any errors or console logs?

Comment: First one has a syntax error before `var schnitt`, where `,` is placed instead of `;`. Besides, `rechne` should be declared **outside** of the DOMContentLoaded event, otherwise it won't be accessible.

Comment: In addition to what @briosheje mentioned, your ending parens are messed up. Hit F12 and bring up a developer console so you can see the errors.

Comment: @mkaatman indeed, nice catch for the parens, didn't notice that :D

Comment: Where's the css?

Answer (score 1):

1) First, read the error message:

> "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var",

2) Then look at your usage of `var`:

```
var mathe = document.getElementById('mathe'),
        deutsch = document.getElementById('deutsch'),
        englisch = document.getElementById('englisch'),
        franzoesisch = document.getElementById('franzoesisch'),

    var schnitt  = mathe.valueAsNumber + deutsch.valueAsNumber + englisch.valueAsNumber + franzoesisch.valueAsNumber;
```

3) Lastly, try double checking the syntax (because the error is a syntax error)

Specifically, you can't do `var x, var y;` in Javascript (nor in most languages). To declare multiple variables you must do either `var x, y` or `var x; var y;`

4) Once you resolve this error, continue repeating steps 1-3 until the remaining errors are resolved (there are more). This process combined with  stackoverflow searching can help resolve most coding problems.

Comment: I have tried fixing the syntax errors. Now I have a Error: Line 17: Unexpected token ). I looked at the syntax from the document.addEventListener and I think that I really need the ). Without it I have a "unexpected end of input" .